# How to check a checkbox in Apex 18 when its value is present in other table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have a checkbox with list of values from table a. I need them to be checked if are present in a column of table b. Do you have any ready solution please colleagues ?
Thx
Adam

Comment: Do you have some code to share?

Answer (score 0):

[See this similar question for some background info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915748/oracle-apex-dynamically-check-checkbox-item-that-is-not-within-a-report?rq=1).

When you're working with a multi-value checkbox item, you want your Source Query to select a *colon-delimited list* of the values that you want to be checked in your checkbox. (This is true for multi-value Application Express page items in general.) E.g.

```
select listagg(my_column, ':') within group (order by my_column) 
from TableB
```

where `my_column` is the name of the column in TableB that your values are stored in.

If you have a lot of values in TableB (enough that the listagg() above returns more than 4000 characters), you'll need a fancier query, but for most cases it'll work fine.